# Can a script by a third-party on my page drill info from the page?

Tags: javascript

let's say I have a page with a script by a third party that is intended to track conversions.

Assuming this third party can't visit the page itself, what can the third party know about my page?

for example, I think they can tell the URL of the page from which the script is being called.

**but can they also find out information about the contents of the page, such as the text and links inside of it?**

Comment: Absolutely yes.

Comment: really? can it even tell what headers are being sent to the client from that page? such as redirection headers?

Comment: Your page is naked, Bucky.

Comment: It has complete access to your page and can make any request to the same domain with cookies. Don’t insert third-party scripts unless you have very good reason to trust them, and even then… still don’t.

Comment: Now you've expanded the question to include headers. Is there anything else you'd like to add? If you're going to include browser extensions and developer tools, then there's absolutely nothing off limits, while a 3rd party script will have limitations to the data it can access.

Comment: Ok, so I want to know the exact limitations of third party javascript. you say that it can scan all elements in the page? but not the headers being sent?

Comment: @squint I'll be more specific. say I want to redirect a visitor, the redirection occurs from a page with a third party script. If it's with `HTTP META REFRESH`, it would show in source, so the third party can tell the redirection destination? the same would be with java redirection. however, a PHP redirection with header refresh - the third party wouldn't be able to tell what's the destination?

Comment: many browsers expose a document.referrer property that says what url redirected the user to the current page. scripts can do about anything a human can, and a whole lot more.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure this has anything to do with my specific question

Comment: my comment addresses both the part about reading page content (yes), and " a PHP redirection with header refresh" (usually). whatever the user san see, so can JS, and JS can see some things the user can't, like <input type=password> field values.

Comment: The document itself is wide open. WRT header data, it is limited in which *original* headers it can read, but it could make an XHR request to obtain more header information from the new request. There are other questions that have dealt with this, so you should be able to find them if you search.

Comment: @Bucky: Usually js on a page cannot access the headers that were sent with the page. However, the script could easily re-request the page with XHR and read headers from there for example. You cannot really hide anything, once the script is executed on your domain you're basically naked and lack of API does not mean something is safe to be considered inaccessible (workarounds are found and new APIs are introduced faster than you'd think :-)

Comment: @Bergi but what if I block access to the page for POST requests only. could the script then still send a succesful XHR request?

Comment: @Bucky: A script in the user's browser on your domain can do anything to your domain that the user can. Sending POST requests per XHR is one of the more trivial things.

Comment: @Bergi but the script can't guess on it's own the correct POST parameters, therefore it can't necessarily see what the real visitor see.

Comment: @Bucky: It can look at forms in the HTML, request other links to find forms, etc.. The rule of thumb, though, is that it can *always* see what the real visitor sees… except for whether a link is `:visited`.